# Typescript not loading the large json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to load my json file in the program.
Using the following code:
**seed.d.ts:**

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

**dataset.ts:**

```
import * as data from "./my.json"
```

I tried to build using the `npm run build` and got the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node_module_register
 2: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewHeapNumber
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewNumber
 6: v8::internal::wasm::AnalyzeLoopAssignmentForTesting
 7: v8::internal::AstValueFactory::Internalize
 8: v8::internal::DeclarationScope::AttachOuterScopeInfo
 9: v8::internal::parsing::ParseProgram
10: v8::internal::compiler::JSTypedLowering::isolate
11: v8::internal::Compiler::GetFunctionFromEval
12: v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeArrayRandomIterator::UpdateOffsetFromIndex
13: v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeArrayRandomIterator::UpdateOffsetFromIndex
14: 000002C1843A449C
```

Let me know what I missed. If you need any other information please ask first.

The **package.json** file is like the following:

```
{
  "name": "deep-playground-prototype",
  "version": "2016.3.10",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {

    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "start": "npm run serve-watch",
    "prep": "copyfiles analytics.js dist && concat node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.js node_modules/seedrandom/seedrandom.min.js > dist/lib.js",
    "build-css": "concat node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.css styles.css > dist/bundle.css",
    "watch-css": "concat node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.css styles.css -o dist/bundle.css",
    "build-html": "copyfiles index.html dist",
    "watch-html": "concat index.html -o dist/index.html",
    "build-js": "browserify src/playground.ts -p [tsify] | uglifyjs -c > dist/bundle.js",
    "watch-js": "watchify src/playground.ts -p [tsify] -v --debug -o dist/bundle.js",
    "build": "npm run prep && npm run build-js && npm run build-css && npm run build-html",
    "watch": "npm run prep && concurrently \"npm run watch-js\" \"npm run watch-css\" \"npm run watch-html\"",
    "serve": "http-server -o -c-1 dist/",
    "serve-watch": "concurrently \"http-server -o -c-1 dist/\" \"npm run watch\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/d3": "^3.5.34",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.28",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "concurrently": "3.1.0",
    "copyfiles": "1.0.0",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "tsify": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9",
    "uglify-js": "^2.8.29",
    "watchify": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "^3.5.16",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "seedrandom": "^2.4.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with typescript. It's node.js running out of memory.

You can try to bypass this problem by running:

```
node --max-old-space-size=2048 `which npm` run build
```

instead of `npm run build`.

Increase the number (2048) if necessary.

Comment: Oh so you're running on windows... replace \`which npm\` with the absolute path to npm

Comment: Is there a way by default I can increase the memory and just run `npm run build`?

Comment: @JafferWilson Sorry, don't know about that... Especially on windows

Comment: I think it's _not_ just down to node running out of memory per se.  In tests with a large `trie` (built from a sowpods list), I can `require` the file in Typescript without a problem, but if I `import` it, then compilation fails.